# how to set H264 profile in android recorder?

Tags: android, h.264, mediarecorder, encoder

I would like to set the H264 encoder's profile, such as Baseline profile / Main profile / Extension profile.

But I can not find an api in MediaRecorder to do it.
The most likely api is MediaRecorder.setProfile(profile),
but it seems only assign some predefined parameters such as fps / bitrate / resolution.

What I want is to let my apk enable/disable 'I,P,B frames' and 'Interlace' etc..which are controlled by H264 profile.
Any idea?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to play with :

```
public int  quality The quality level of the camcorder profile
```

?